# What does the $ mean in $MATPLOTLIBRC/matplotlibrc?

Tags: matplotlib

Originally from the Matplotlib website, https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html

The directory

```
$MATPLOTLIBRC/matplotlibrc
```

is the second place matplotlib will look for its rc file.

I have been reading around, but have not found a suitable answer. In some cases, $ can indicate windows uninstallation files, and safely deletable.

Comment: I think ive found out what it means. It tells the bash to replace $MATPLOTLIBRC with the directory of matplotlibrc. So MATPLOTLIBRC is an environmental variable.

Comment: But #MATPLOTLIBRC isn't listed as an environmental variable here https://matplotlib.org/faq/environment_variables_faq.html#envvar-MPLCONFIGDIR

Comment: Although I haven't tested it, I would also interprete it this way: `MATPLOTLIBRC` is an evironment variable which you can set to a path containing the rc file.